# Connect to workgroup computers by name behind ASA 5505 with VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, cisco-asa

We have a Windows workgroup sitting behind an ASA 5505.
All clients receive their IP assignment from the ASA.

VPN is set up and we can connect to the local LAN and connect to the machines by IP, but not by their hostnames.

Inside all machines can connect through hostnames and we would like to do the same when the users are connected through the VPN.

Is this possible with machines just being in a workgroup, dns set up inside and outside coming from Google and no domain set on the ASA?

Comment: How are names being resolved now?  NetBIOS broadcasts?

Comment: From the one computer I can access at the moment, Network Discovery is turned on under Homegroup options.  Netbios over TCP is enabled. Win7 Professional if that helps.